# Where can I find articles about high voltage power supply (HVPS)?

Tags: power-supply

I've been searching Google for almost 2 hours and haven't find anything good about HVPS yet. 95% of the results are the descriptions of shopping websites which are not enough at all.
Is there any article about HVPS? I need something saying how a HVPS works and what parts it has.

Edit:
By "high voltage" I mean 1000V to 10000V.
I searched for "high voltage power supply", "HVPS" and "how does a high voltage power supply work".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 1) Not "all knowledge" can be learned from Google. I know lots of things that I learned at work that you will not find anywhere. 2) "High voltage" is not clear. I usually design low voltage circuits powered by 5 V, then 100 V would be "high voltage". To a designer of mains supplies, 400 V is common so to them 100 V isn't that much. So be specific about what you mean by "high voltage", 100 V, 1000 V, 10 000 V ?

Comment: what search words were you using?

Comment: Same components as regular power supplies but with higher voltage rating?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It's for my university. Something general would be enough. By high voltage I mean 1000V to 10000V.

Comment: @jsotola I searched for "high voltage power supply", "HVPS" and "how does a high voltage power supply work".

Comment: that's like wanting info about red apples and searching for "red" ... you are trying to find an "article" ...  try "high voltage power supply article" ... also try "high voltage power supply theory of operation"

Comment: Thanks for the tip @jsotola

Comment: Go to one of the major IC manufacturers websites that makes power control IC's and search their application notes.   i.e. Texas Instruments etc...

Comment: @MaHdi Also go to [DIY Physics](https://www.diyphysics.com/category/instrumentation/high-voltage-power-supply/).

Comment: What minimal specifications ? Voltage, positive, negative, current, power, ripple, programmable, etc  ... ?

Comment: ROFL  [Building the HVPS—High Voltage Power Supply](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-02x-physics-ii-electricity-magnetism-with-an-experimental-focus-spring-2005/labs/building_hvps.pdf) [High voltage power supply (1 to 20 KV)](https://physlab.lums.edu.pk/images/2/24/Hv_power_supply.pdf)  First [Google page](https://physlab.lums.edu.pk/images/2/24/Hv_power_supply.pdf) links.

Comment: Interesting also this ...  https://www.voltagemultipliers.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Multiplier-Design-Guideline.pdf . I used such voltage multiplier (x10, 1N4007G - 1000V reverse) with a "reverse" little transformer 50Hz - 25 VA - 2*6V -> 220V , driven by a sinusoidal generator at the "best" frequency ...

Comment: To get a better search try this: add a verb before the device name. Example "using HVPS" or "installing HVPS". That pushes the selling sites away and brings up more useful sites.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is your choice of key words. Yet using  HVPS on Google Images, I found this immediately on Researchgate.net (free membership)

I just used HVPS, but you can use HVPS + design + voltage.

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Somayyeh-Rahimi/publication/332673916_Phase-Shifted_Half-Bridge_Resonant_Inverter_For_Driving_Magnetron/links/5ea9724aa6fdcc705097d277/Phase-Shifted-Half-Bridge-Resonant-Inverter-For-Driving-Magnetron.pdf?origin=figuresDialog_download